# Java - Checking matching parenthesis with additional '&' character

Tags: java, hashmap, stack, matching, parentheses

I wrote a function to check whether parenthesis are balanced, i.e {([])} true, {(}) false. But I'm now trying to figure out how to account for an extra character '&' that matches with itself, i.e &{&&}& true, &{&} false. I tried just counting the number of '&'s to see if it's even, but that doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

```
public static boolean isBalanced(String input) {
    if (input == null || input.length() == 1) return false;
    int size = input.length();
    if (size % 2 == 1) return false;

    Stack<Character> stack = new Stack<Character>();
    HashMap<Character, Character> map = new HashMap<Character, 
    Character>();
    map.put('(', ')');
    map.put('[', ']');
    map.put('{', '}');

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        char temp = input.charAt(i);
        if (map.containsKey(temp)) stack.push(temp);
        else if (stack.isEmpty() || map.get(stack.pop()) != temp) 
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: try checking the closing condition `]})&` before the opening condition `[{(&`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you see a `&`, and the top of the stack is a `&`, then pop it, otherwise push the `&`.

For your code to handle that, without treating `&` specially, simply swap the code to check the `stack` before the `map`.

Other issues with your code:

- The [`Stack`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html) class is a legacy class, built on top of the synchronized [`Vector`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html) class. As the javadoc says, you should use [`Deque`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html) instead.
- Don't collapse your statements too much. Put the statement controlled by `if` on its own line, for improved human readability.
- Don't use `==` (or `!=`) to compare objects, use `equals()`.
- You forgot to check if the stack is empty after the loop, to make sure there are no dangling pairs.

```java
public static boolean isBalanced(String input) {
    if (input == null)
        return false;
    int size = input.length();
    if (size % 2 == 1)
        return false;

    HashMap<Character, Character> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put('(', ')');
    map.put('[', ']');
    map.put('{', '}');
    map.put('&', '&');

    Deque<Character> stack = new ArrayDeque<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        Character temp = input.charAt(i); // autobox here so it only happens once
        if (temp.equals(stack.peek())) // equals is false if stack is empty, since peek returns null
            stack.pop();
        else if (map.containsKey(temp))
            stack.push(map.get(temp));
        else
            return false;
    }

    return stack.isEmpty();
}
```

*Test*

```java
System.out.println(isBalanced("{([])}"));
System.out.println(isBalanced("{(})"));
System.out.println(isBalanced("&{&&}&"));
System.out.println(isBalanced("&{&}"));
System.out.println(isBalanced("(("));
```

*Output*

```
true
false
true
false
false
```